# Need helping find examples/instruction

Tags: recursion

Going through some exercises, and my book isn't very helpful in illustrating solutions. Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me dissect what is taking place here?

Need a recursive function to model:

T( n) = n                  when n%2 = 0

T( n) = 2 + T(n-1)   when n%2 = 1

Thanks!

Comment: The sample you have is not good for recursion as it only returns `n` when `n` is even and `n+1` when n is odd. The best recursion example would be to find the factorial of a number.

Comment: alvits - thanks or the insight. I will look into that.

Comment: `T(n)` is often used to represent the amount of time a function takes on a problem of size `n`.  Are you sure you aren't misinterpreting what the book and its exercises are asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
function T(n) 
{
    if(n%2 == 0) 
        return n;
    else if(n%2 == 1)
        return 2 + T(n-1);
}


So lets say you use 3, then the function enters check 3%2 that's not 0 so it pases to the     else
which now has 3/2 and that returns the following:
function T(3) 
{
    if(n%2 == 0) 
        return n;
    else if(n%2 == 1)
        return 2 + T(n-1); // T(3-1) = T(2)
} 
This here would be equivalent to calling the same function
but now with a 2 instead of a 3 and the return statement would then be added to the 
original 2 and so on, I hope I explained a bit.
function T(2) 
{
    if(n%2 == 0) 
        return n;
    else if(n%2 == 1)
        return 2 + T(n-1);
}
```

Comment: Deceptively simple. Thanks for your assistance! I need to play around with more examples - recursion is still a bit over my head.

Comment: +1 for giving a very simple explanation that is easily understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python code:

```
def rec(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        return n;
    else: # if n%2 == 1
        return 2 + rec(n-1)

print(rec(9)) # 10
print(rec(10)) # 10
print(rec(11)) # 12
print(rec(12)) # 12
```

But where is the problem? By the way, it is not really recursive, because the function is called maximum one time 'recursively'.

Comment: +1 That's exactly what i mentioned in my comment to the OP. When `n` is even, it returns `n` and when `n` is odd it returns `n+1`. But giving a simple example is a good start for any beginners.

Comment: I was confused, so I'm glad some of you find issue with the example. I will be spending a lot more time on Stack Overflow to help supplement my studies. Thanks again!